# Unable to add CrmDeploymentService Web Reference due to Authentication Issue

Tags: c#, web-services, internet-explorer-8, dynamics-crm, basic-authentication

I am having an issue adding a Web Service Reference to the CRM Deployment Service at http:///MSCRMServices/2007/CrmDeploymentService.asmx

When I first attempt to connect it says Connecting to  and prompts for credentials. After entering my credentials, it will continue to prompting for credentials indefinately.

When I attempt to navigate to the service in IE, I get prompted for credentials and after submitting them a few times, I get a 401 error.

When I attempt to navigate to the service in Firefox or Opera, the basic authentication dialog pops up and I enter credentials. The service description page correctly appears.

Is there something preventing IE/VS from submitting the credentials correctly? In each place, I am using the same domain/user credentials. I have tried it from IE on both a computer on the domain and a computer not on the domain and get the same results.

Comment: Changing the URL to http://<IP Address>/MSCRMServices/2007/CrmDeploymentService.asmx fixed the problem. Pinging the server resolves the IP Address to the same IP Address used in the browser and the website is bound to All Unassigned. Firefox and Opera are still working fine, but IE/Visual studio still break when I use the server name. If anyone knows why this is happening, I'd still appreciate knowing what's going on.

Comment: My guess is that there's an issue where IE is trying to use Kerberos and the other browsers are using NTLM. You may be able to see the difference with Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I vaguely remember something like this happening to us at work, and someone fixed it by disabling IPV6.  Like I said my memory is hazy so I don't know if this is the exact problem that we were having too.  I just remember that the solution was to disable IPV6 on the server.